# How can I make an integrationTest source set with groovy in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm trying to add multiple test directories to my android project. I'd ideally like a unite test directory, and a integration test directories. I do all my unite tests in Spock, and I'd like to do all of my integration tests using Spock or robospock. The problem is, in my Gradle build file I keep getting errors when I try to do this:

```
android {
    sourceSets{
            integrationTest {
                groovy {
                    test.groovy.srcDir 'src/integrationTest/groovy'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get this error:

> Error:(77, 0) Could not find method groovy() for arguments
>   [build_c07qe1tzsdi2876irgi5e3c6i$_run_closure2$_closure9$_closure12$_closure13@7f835189]
>   on source set integration test of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet.

this works when I do use java:

```
android {
    sourceSets{
        integrationTest {
            java {
                test.java.srcDir 'src/integrationTest/java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin:

```
androidGroovy {
        sourceSets {
            integrationTest {
                groovy {
                    srcDirs += 'src/integrationTest/groovy'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'`, and I've successfully gotten spock tests to run in the test directory, so my groovy configuration is working, I'm just not able to add more groovy test directories.

I get the same error as above on this one. I also have tried them outside of the android wrapper to no avail.

I'd seriously be so grateful to anyone who could at lest point me in the right direction. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Do you apply the groovy plugin?

Comment: ya I have `apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android'` and I my test directory with spock works fine. I just can't seem to get another build path with groovy working. And since integration tests are much slower than unite tests I don't really want to mix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out I was using an old version of the android groovy compiler. you need to do this: `apply plugin: 'groovyx.android'` which is the new name for `groovyx.grooid.groovy-android` and you need to add this class path to your dependencies. Note this should probably go in your root project dependencies not in the class dependencies, because it needs to happen before the apply statement.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-android-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
}
```

then you can do this:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/integration-test/groovy'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/unit-test/groovy'
    }
}
```

only took me like two days to figure that out. :D